SAPUI5 Basic Template use of Annotations
I am having requirement to use value help that was created using @Consumption.valueHelpDefinition.
I have used them in different UI5-based templates. There is no need of extra coding for that.
Is there any possibility of using those annotation-based charts and valueHelps in Basic Template of SAPUI5?
